why does quasar not show errors in dev mode
Using "Visual Studio Code" for our quasar project, I see an error if I open a vue file:

This error actually causes the q-table not to be displayed, which is more serious than a simple warning. Visual Studio Code also declares it an Error.
What I don't understand is why quasar doesn't show the error when I run quasar dev:

Especially since Visual Studio Code only shows errors in the currently open file. The above error was introduced by a quasar update and was completely missed as I don't open all our files to check for errors.  
How to get VSCode to show TypeScript errors for files *not* open in the editor?
EDIT (adding details to the error):
The cause of the error is that the referenced usages is declared undefined first, so it might not only be a typescript issue:
usages: undefined as [] | undefined,


You could run a checker on all your files before committing. But otherwise, I guess that Quasar does not handle this part. That doesn't shock me that TS errors are not part of it. They might be quite breaking regarding the consequences but it was maybe judged not important enough by the core team to be implemented as a default configuration. I am not sure how good Quasar is with TS. Nuxt might be better on that regard.

You can try the workaround provided here: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/15448 to enable type checking on dev env.

The error doesn't cause erroneous behaviour, just indicates a possible reason. It's unknown under which condition usages is undefined, the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . See https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview . It's your responsibility to use vue-tsc to check types in templates
